# How to apply a polymorphic function to a Dynamic value

Tags: haskell, types, dynamic-typing

Is there a sane way to apply a polymorphic function to a value of type `Dynamic`?

For instance, I have a value of type `Dynamic` and I want to apply `Just` to the value inside the `Dynamic`.  So if the value was constructed by `toDyn True` I want the result to be `toDyn (Just True)`.  The number of different types that can occur inside the `Dynamic` is not bounded.

(I have a solution when the types involved come from a closed universe, but it's unpleasant.)

Comment: Looks like `polytypeable` and `polytypeable-utils` could be used for this - though you'd still have to implement full unification, in the worst case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is perhaps not the sanest approach, but we can abuse my `reflection` package to lie about a TypeRep.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types, FlexibleContexts, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.Dynamic
import Data.Proxy
import Data.Reflection
import GHC.Prim (Any)
import Unsafe.Coerce

newtype WithRep s a = WithRep { withRep :: a }

instance Reifies s TypeRep => Typeable (WithRep s a) where
  typeOf s = reflect (Proxy :: Proxy s)
```

Given that we can now peek at the `TypeRep` of our `Dynamic` argument and instantiate our `Dynamic` function appropriately.

```
apD :: forall f. Typeable1 f => (forall a. a -> f a) -> Dynamic -> Dynamic
apD f a = dynApp df a
  where t = dynTypeRep a
        df = reify (mkFunTy t (typeOf1 (undefined :: f ()) `mkAppTy` t)) $ 
                  \(_ :: Proxy s) -> toDyn (WithRep f :: WithRep s (() -> f ()))
```

It could be a lot easier if `base` just supplied something like `apD` for us, but that requires a rank 2 type, and `Typeable`/`Dynamic` manage to avoid them, even if `Data` does not.

Another path would be to just exploit the implementation of `Dynamic`:

```
data Dynamic = Dynamic TypeRep Any
```

and `unsafeCoerce` to your own `Dynamic'` data type, do what you need to do with the `TypeRep` in the internals, and after applying your function, `unsafeCoerce` everything back.

Comment: Lying about the `TypeRep` is ingenious, so I'll accept this answer (using `unsafeCoerce` to peek&poke inside `Dynamic` does not qualify as sane).

Comment: @augustss: Where is the moral difference?

Comment: @AndreasRossberg It's very small. :)  But the former is somewhat more robust.  For instance, if the implementation of `Dynamic` changes so the `TypeRep` and `Any` fields change place the former would still work while the latter crashes.

Comment: This won't work any more now that you can't write custom `Typeable` instances, right?

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam, Edward Kmett officially proposed a fix to the underlying issue today. We'll see where that goes.

Comment: Your question prompted me to post it. =)

Comment: So, what is the solution to this now? Did that proposal go anywhere?

Comment: With GHC 8.0 there will be a new 'proper' TypeRep that will actually contain the 'a' in the type. This will make a lot of these sorts of hacks a lot easier and safer to do.